# bash to create sub directories in folder from specific file extension

Tags: bash

In the `bash` below I am trying to create sub-directories inside a directory from files with specific `.bam` extentions. The `.bam` file are trimmed and the result is the folder name that is saved in `$RDIR` or one level up from where  the original files are found.There may be multiple `.bam` files but they are always the same format. I made comments as well. Thank you :).

**bash**

```
DIR=/home/cmccabe/Desktop/folder   ## define data directory path
cd "$DIR" || exit 1  # check directory exists or exit
for RDIR in R_2019* ; do  ## start processing matching "R_2019*" to operate on desired directory and expand
 cd "$RDIR"/BAM   ## change directory to subfolder inside $RDIR
  bam=$(find . -type f -name "*.bam")   # extract .bam
  sample="$(echo $bam|cut -d_ -f3-)" # remove before second underscore
  mkdir -p "${sample%.*}" && mv "$sample" "RDIR"/"${x%.*}"  ## make directory of sample id one level up
done  ## close loop
```

**structure of `/home/cmccabe/Desktop/folder`  --- this is $DIR ---**

```
R_2019_00_00_00_00_00_xxxx_xx-0000-00  --- this is $RDIR ---
     BAM   ---subdirectory---
       IonCode_0241_19-0000-Last-First.bam.bai
       IonCode_0241_19-0000-Last-First.bam
       IonCode_0243_19-0001-Las-Fir.bam.bai
       IonCode_0243_19-0001-Las-Fir.bam
     QC    ---subdirectory---
```

**after script structure of `/home/cmccabe/Desktop/folder`  --- this is $DIR** ---

```
R_2019_00_00_00_00_00_xxxx_xx-0000-00  --- this is $RDIR ---
     BAM                  ---subdirectory---
     19-0000-Last-First   ---subdirectory---
     19-0001-Las-Fir      ---subdirectory---
     QC                   ---subdirectory---
```

**set -x**

```
bash: cd: R_2019*/BAM: No such file or directory
++ find . -type f -name '*.bam'
+ bam=
++ echo
++ cut -d_ -f3-
+ sample=
+ mkdir -p ''
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘’: No such file or directory
```

Comment: What is the issue? Does the code work the way you want? If not, in what way?

Comment: `bam=$(find . -type f -name "*.bam")   # extract .bam` is not extracted.... bash: cd: R_2019*/BAM: No such file or directory... mkdir: cannot create directory ‘’: No such file or directory.... I think the `find`is not working as expected, but not sure how to fix it. I added `set -x to the post as well. Thank you :).

Comment: Well, your `cd "$RDIR"/BAM` fail before it gets to `find` and it fails because `R_2019*` doesn't match anything (leaving the pattern unexpanded).

Comment: Also related: [Why is looping over find's output bad practice?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/321697)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be issue with following line:

```
 bam=$(find . -type f -name "*.bam")   # extract .bam
 sample="$(echo $bam|cut -d_ -f3-)" # remove before second underscore
```

### **Modifications:**

This can be achieved in one line:

```
i=$(find . -type f -name "*.bam" -print | while read f;do echo "$f" | cut -d_ -f3-;done| cut -f 1 -d '.') ## To take the file names and then cut.
```

and then add for loop to make dir:

```
for x in $i
        do mkdir -p $DIR/$x
        done
```

### **Final Script:**

```
DIR=/home/vvek/MyLearning/Linux/bam/   ## define data directory path
cd "$DIR" || exit 1  # check directory exists or exit
for RDIR in R_2019* ; do  ## start processing matching "R_2019*" to operate on desired directory and expand
 cd "$RDIR"/BAM   ## change directory to subfolder inside $RDIR
i=$(find . -type f -name "*.bam" -print | while read f;do echo "$f" | cut -d_ -f2-;done| cut -f 1 -d '.')  # extract .bam

for x in $i
        do mkdir -p $DIR/$x
        done
done  ## close loop
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and explanatiom.m :)

Comment: Happy to be helpful.. keep learning :p